# i18 translate link_to text rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Hi I need to design a application running in English and Spanish .Is there any option in rails like button for translation of link_to tag text
I am looking for option similar to this

```
helpers:
submit:
  # This will be the default ones, will take effect if no other
  # are specifically defined for the models.
  create: "Créer %{model}"
  update: "Modifier %{model}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all [described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

You will need to save your Spanish and English translations in: config/locales/es.yml and config/locales/en.yml respectively.

For link texts you can do something like:

```
es:
  links:
    home: "Casa"
```

Then you can call:

```
<%= link_to t('links.home'), root_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your locales file (the indentation was incorrect):

```
helpers:
  submit:
    # This will be the default ones, will take effect if no other
    # are specifically defined for the models.
    create: "Créer %{model}"
    update: "Modifier %{model}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two files:  `config/locales/es.yml` & `config/locales/en.yml` and define the Spenish and English content in their own files.

Then define your links like:

```
<% link_to t('path.to.key'), your_url %>
```

I have done similar work in my app for switching English & Swahilli.

**Switching language code:**

View:

```
<div class="pull-right">
  <% [:en, :swa].each do |language| %>
    <%= link_to language.to_s.upcase, change_language_path(language), class: "btn btn-info #{'disabled' if language == I18n.locale}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def change_language
  cookies[:language] = params[:language]

  redirect_to :back
end
```

Route.rb

```
match 'change_language/:language' => 'my_controller#change_language', as: 'change_language'
```